# BFS traversal with ingoing edges in Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j

Say in a cypher database we have nodes, A,B,C, ... , Z. Say we record our relationships via something like A -> B, so A goes to B, but B can also go to A, so B -> A too. Currently, I need to perform Breadth-first search (BFS) so that we start from A and then we traverse the graph based on "ingoing" nodes.

So A <- B, A <- C, A <- D and we have A -> B, A-> E. We specifically should be traversing from A to (B,C,D) and not E because we can only traverse ingoing edges. I currently know Cyper queries which can do BFS, following a specific relationship but is it possible to manually do this in Cypher too?

Thank you

Comment: One option is to use APOC plugin with apoc.path.expandConfig. This should be the most efficient way to do it on neo4j, but it is not pure Cypher. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Hi, do you know what the command for that would be? Currently when I run any BFS or any match algorithm , when looking for outgoing relationships specifically it still displays incoming edges.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use APOC plugin you can do something like:

The `relationshipFilter:"<"` means traversing only "against" the direction of the link:

```
    MATCH (start:Node{key:'A'})
    WITH start
    CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(start, {bfs: true, relationshipFilter:"<"})
    YIELD nodes, relationships
    RETURN nodes, relationships
```

Or:

```
    MATCH (start:Node{key:'A'})
    WITH start
    CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {bfs: true, relationshipFilter:"<"})
    YIELD path
    RETURN path
```

According to the [docs](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expandConfig/), `bfs` is the default here anyway.

**EDIT**: you can add `maxLevel` to limit the depth:

```
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {bfs: true, maxLevel: 2, relationshipFilter:"<"})
```

You can try it on:

```
MERGE (a:Node{key: 'A'})    
MERGE (b:Node{key: 'B'})
MERGE (c:Node{key: 'C'})
MERGE (d:Node{key: 'D'})
MERGE (e:Node{key: 'E'})
MERGE (f:Node{key: 'F'})
MERGE (g:Node{key: 'G'})

MERGE (b)-[:POINTS]-(a)
MERGE (c)-[:POINTS]-(a)
MERGE (d)-[:POINTS]-(a) 
MERGE (e)-[:POINTS]-(d) 
MERGE (f)-[:POINTS]-(c)
MERGE (g)-[:POINTS]-(c)
```

Comment: So, what does the "<" filter out? Does this mean you only get outgoing relationships, and in conjunction to this is there a way I can specify depth to this?

Comment: Yes, this means traversing only "against" the direction of the link

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I see, so it does work however the relationshsips between other nodes are ALSO displayed, what I wanted was, say for a maxLevel search of 1, ONLY the links from 'A" and it's outgoing Nodes, these other Nodes seem to display there own relationships too which is not what I want. Thank you

Comment: Please notice: on neo4j UI there is a difference between what you see on the UI and the output data. Check `table` or `text` option instead of `graph` to see the real result. `graph` option is showing all the relationships between all returned nodes, by default,  even if they are not part of the response

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. Thank you for letting me know! But this all was very helpful!

Comment: There is a way to disable this option for the `graph`, but the default is "lying"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245653/discussion-between-steveit-and-nimrod-serok).